# Tengo un problema al unir varias variables en BATCH (cmd) con el simbolo "&"

Tags: cmd, batch

Este es el problema:

```
set /a var1= %todo% & echo %linea%>>%exename%
set todo= %var1%`
```

Lo que quiero es que `%var1%` contenga toda la información de arriba, y luego se lo pase a `%todo%`

Principalmente es eso y el `&` se detecta como si fuese más de 1 comando en una línea.

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar la bandera `/a` para expresiones aritméticas que contienen operaciones lógicas es necesario encerrar la expresión entre comillas dobles (`"..."`):

```
set /a "var1=%todo% & %linea%>>%exename%"
set "todo=%var1%"
```

Aquí un enlace con información y ejemplos:
https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions

Comment: A ver, muchas gracias, pero creo que no me explique bien, mira mi respuesta... (Voy a escribir una respuesta nueva, soy nuevo aqui y no estoy seguro de que hacer para responderte.)

Answer (score 0):

A ver: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que `%var1%` es igual a 0 por que los elementos `&` y `>>` lo bloquean.

**Lo siento por poner la imagen, el código no se me pone como tal, pero de todas formas aqui esta:**

```
@echo off  
set exename= Ejemplo  

:loop  
set /p linea= Nueva linea (Escribe 0 para terminar.):  
if %linea%== 0 goto guardar  
set /a "var1=%todo% & %linea%>>%exename%"  
set todo= %var1%  
echo %var1%  
pause  
goto loop
```